# adaptive histogram equalization

Tags: code-request, image-processing

There is an interesting algorithm called [contrast enhanced adaptive histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization) that does histogram equalization on small segments of an image (and then pastes them back together). I know Mathematica has the [HistogramTransform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramTransform.html) function to do equalization on the whole image. It also has a [local method of binarizing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalAdaptiveBinarize.html), but I don't believe I have seen a local (adaptive) equalization. Has anyone implemented this (or similar) algorithms?

Comment: With a 512x512 greyscale image, you could partition and get a binning for all blocks:  `bins = 256; blocksz = 64;
levmap = Map[
   N@Accumulate@ImageLevels[#, bins][[All, 2]]/(blocksz^2) &, 
   ImagePartition[img, 64], {2}];`. For example `levmap[[2,3]]` would get a CDF (in list form) of the (2,3) block. Then I presume you interpolate the resulting array and to get CDF's for all pixels.

Comment: @Histograms This draft of an answer seems promising. Do you think you could complete the process as you described and post it as an answer?

Comment: @MarcoB I got something working but I read about it and I don't think it's what bill wants. I was interpolating the cdf histograms themselves, but from reading about it, the interpolation is done on pixel values, not distributions. Best I can offer is `ImageAssemble@
 Map[HistogramTransform, ImagePartition[img, blocksize], {2}]` and then somebody would need to figure out how to interpolate those grey values, I can't work that bit out.

Comment: @Histograms OK thank you for the update!

Comment: Check the documentation about [`HistogramTransformInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramTransformInterpolation.html), section `Applications > Locally adaptive histogram equalization`. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @shrx - I feel really silly now -- I don't know how I missed that. It is exactly what I was looking for... and it works great in my application as well. Thanks!